# How can I debug a MinGW EXE with the Microsoft Visual C++ debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, debugging, mingw

How can I debug a MinGW EXE with the Microsoft Visual C++ debugger?

Answer (score 4):

You can attach the Visual C++ debugger to any process running on the system (from the Visual C++ menu). But for being able to step through your source code Visual C++ would have to load the symbol file (.pdb if I remember correctly) and I don't think GCC generates those files.

Answer (score 2):

**The Problem:**

GCC compiler (ie MinGW's gcc) generates debug info with "-g" flag. The debug info is embedded into the generated executable. Windows' compiler, on the other hand, uses a peculiar ".pdb" format to store the debug info. For example, Microsoft Visual Studio's debugger needs not only the executable (.exe), but also its debug info (.pdb) to be available.

**The Solution:**

There is a small program that can extract .pdb files from executables compiled with gcc.
It is called cv2pdb, available at https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb.

- Download cv2pdb https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb
- Put the cv2pdb.exe somewhere in your path, maybe a custom bin folder, so that it will be accessible through the command line.
- Compile your file as usual using MinGW's gcc compiler, with the "-g" flag, so that the debug info is included.
- Simply run cv2pdb.exe on your executable.

  cv2pdb out.exe

  This will generate a out.pdb file in the same directory.
- (If you have Microsoft Visual Studio installed) Open the executable directly in Microsoft Visual  Studio

  devenv out.exe

**Note:** This command simply opens the executable in Microsoft Visual Studio, without creating a project for it. In effect, you can use whatever text editor + build system you want to build your executable, and then use Visual studio only as a standalone debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Exists many Visual studio extensions such us: WinGDB, VisualGDB you can find it on the web. It allows you to debug as regular Visual Studio project. These projects are not free but it has full functional 30 days trial. It has some restrictions but it's good enough.